# How to upgrade react-leaflet from v.2.8 to v.3

Tags: react-leaflet-v3

I'm using react-leaflet v.2.8 in my project. I want to upgrade the react-leaflet to v.3. But how? When I write "npm i react-leaflet", it installed only react-leaflet v.2.8.

Comment: Try to typing `npm i react-leaflet@latest`.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

`npm uninstall react-leaflet`

`npm install react-leaflet`

Another way:

Go to your package.json, and change whatever version number react-leaflet has to the latest one that is listed on npm.  It should then look like this in the package.json:

`"react-leaflet": "^3.2.0"`

Then run `npm install react-leaflet`

Keep in mind there are lots of breaking changes from version 2 to version 3, so be prepared to update your codebase.